# Chrome extensions WebRequest filtering by tabId not working?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I'm refactoring an existing chrome extension and I have a call to `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders` which should be filtered according to the currently selected tab.

I'm using the documentation [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) and, with regards to the filtering it states:

> The webRequest.RequestFilter filter allows limiting the requests for
>   which events are triggered in various dimensions:
>
> URLs URL patterns such as *://www.google.com/foo*bar. Types Request
>   types such as main_frame (a document that is loaded for a top-level
>   frame), sub_frame (a document that is loaded for an embedded frame),
>   and image (an image on a web site). See webRequest.RequestFilter. Tab
>   ID The identifier for one tab. Window ID The identifier for a window.

From this, it is my understanding that if I define a tabid as part of the listener, I should have all the requests filtered according to the tab ID (therefore, only catching the requests headers coming from that particular tab).

The problem is that this does not happen. When I adopt the tabid:xx filter I keep catching all the requests coming from the various tabs I have opened.

What am I missing?

Here is my sample code from the background script **background.html**:

```
var currentTabId = -1;

chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){ 
    currentTabId = tab.id;
    console.log("tab id in getselected "+currentTabId);

});

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    function(req){

        console.log("-> Request Headers received for "+req.url);

        console.log('onBeforeSendHeaders tab id: '+currentTabId)
        console.log('onBeforeSendHeaders: '+JSON.stringify(req))
    }

, { urls:["http://*/*", "https://*/*"], tabId: currentTabId }, ['requestHeaders','blocking']);
```

currentTabId is e.g. 1666 while the tabId in the object req is another one, that could come from any of the tabs I have opened and I'm using (it's not filtered out on 1666).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sample code has wrong execution order; `chrome.tabs.getSelected` is asynchronous.

```
var currentTabId = -1;
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){
    currentTabId = tab.id;
    // Here, currentTabId is defined properly
    console.log("tab id in getselected "+currentTabId);
});
// Here, it is still -1
```

You need to move your `addListener` call into the `getSelected` callback:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){ 
    currentTabId = tab.id;
    console.log("tab id in getselected "+currentTabId);
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(/*...*/);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I guess -1 as tabId filter value just captures all of the header events.

Comment: Moreover, I know I should use `chrome.tabs.query({active:true})`... this was just an old example.